# Is there any way to run Jubula tests from console?

Tags: console, jubula

I want to run prewritten Jubula tests (possibly on remote machine) from console and receive output in logfile. Is there any way to do it? I haven't found any information about that nor in Google neither in Jubula help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is!

You need to call the testexec.exe (It's placed in "jubula_install"/jubula/ folder)

It has a LOT of parameters and many of them is mandatory. See them below:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Fmanual%2Fnode260.html

Thus I'd recommend you writing batch files for your favorite configurations.